# R - Perform Melt on Each Data Frame in a List

Tags: r, reshape

I have a several data files in a directory (all tsvs). One data file will look like this:

```
Killed    Rick    Darryl    Herschel    Tyrese    Shane
Zombies   200     300       20          4         100
People    10      2         0           0         0
Dogs      0       0         0           0         0
```

The next data file would like this:

```
Killed    Jon    Rob    Varys    Ned    Joeffry   Mormont
Whites    1      0      0        0      0         0
People    0      10     1        30     0         100
```

I would like to merge it so that the data files would read like this:

```
Killed   Variable    Value
Zombies  Rick        200
Zombies  Darryl      300
Zombies  Herschel    20
Zombies  Tyrese      4
Zombies  Shane       100
People   Rick        10
People   Darryl      2
People   Herschel    0
People   Tyrese      0
People   Shane       0
Dogs     Rick        0
Dogs     Darryl      0
Dogs     Herschel    0
Dogs     Tyrese      0
Dogs     Shane       0
Whites   Jon         1
Whites   Rob         0
Whites   Varys       0
Whites   Ned         0
Whites   Joeffry     0
Whites   Mormont     0
People   Jon         0
People   Rob         10
People   Varys       1
People   Ned         30
People   Joeffry     0
People   Mormont     100
```

I would like to parse through the directory and load all the data into R, and then melt each data frame using the reshape package. I would use rbind to combine all of the data frames into a single data frame. Here is the code I have so far:

```
library(reshape)

filenames <- list.files(pattern='*.tsv')

names <- substr(filenames,1, nchar(filenames)-4)

newmelt <- function(x) {
  x <- melt(x, id=c("ID_REF"))
}

for (i in names){
  filepath <- file.path(paste(i,".tsv", sep=""))
  assign(i, read.csv(filepath, sep="\t"))
}

sapply(names(names), newmelt)
```

I know that I can get the results I want using this:

```
test <- read.csv("marvel.tsv", sep="\t")
test.m <- melt(test, id=c("Killed"))
```

But I'm not sure how I can apply this over all the data frames in my list.

Thank you for reading!

EDIT: I suddenly words.

Comment: Is the result supposed to be one big combined melted data frame, or a list of melted data frames?

Comment: @joran Yes, which I would like to write to a file.

Comment: `melt.list` exists and will call `melt.data.frame` on each component, so you could do `melt(lapply(filenames, read.table), id=c("Killed"))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of things to point out here.

First, you really should be using **reshape2**, **reshape** is no longer under development.

Second, avoid using `assign` (generally) but especially in situations like these. It's not very "R-ish" and it will lead to bad habits and hard to debug problems.

Third, if you files really are tab separated, don't use `read.csv` (read the documentation notes on `read.csv` carefully, it's not what you want!), use `read.table`.

I would approach this more like this:

```
library(reshape2)

filenames <- list.files(pattern='*.tsv')

myfun <- function(x){
    dat <- read.table(x,sep = "\t",header = TRUE)
    melt(dat,id.vars = "Killed")
}

#Just iterate over the file paths
# calling one function that reads in the file and melts
out <- lapply(filenames,myfun)
#Put them all together into one data frame
out <- do.call(rbind,out)
```